# Guardar y mostrar palabras introducidas al array desde un archivo js diferente

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tengo 2 archivos html con sus respectivos archivos js. Tengo que añadir mediante el input del html(nombre: challenge02-v2-02.html) palabras al segundo html(challenge02.html). Sin embargo cuando hago el .push() no se me agregan las palabras y me salen algunos errores. Por lo que pude observar en la consola el error está en el .addEventListener del archivo (agregar-palabra.js) y en

```
document.querySelector('#salida00').innerHTML = palabraConGuiones; // (challenge02.js)
```

Comparto los 2 archivos html con sus respectivos js:

```js
// (challenge02.js)
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) { return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length); }

let palabras = ['CASA','PERRO','GATO','ELEFANTE'];

let palabra = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random()*palabras.length)];

let palabraConGuiones = palabra.replace(/./g, "_ ");

let contadorFallos = 6;

document.querySelector('#salida00').innerHTML = palabraConGuiones; // Apartir de acá me sale error

document.getElementById('letra00').addEventListener('keyup', function(){

    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()

});
```

```html
// (challenge02.html)
<input type="text" maxlength="1" placeholder="Ingrese su Letra" id="letra00">

<button id='boton00'>Evaluar letra</button>

<p id="salida00"></p>



<script src='challenge02.js'></script>

<script src="agregar-palabra.js"></script>
```

```js
// (agregar-palabra.js)
//Acá me sale error desde la pantalla del otro html
document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
    
    this.value = this.value.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")

    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();

});

let datos = [];

function agregarPalabra(){

    let dato = document.getElementById('texto').value.toUpperCase();

    palabras.push(dato);

}

function mostrarPalabra(){

    let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

    resultado.innerHTML = '';

    for(let dato of datos){

        let datoParrafo = document.createElement('p');

        datoParrafo.innerText = dato;

        resultado.appendChild(datoParrafo);

    }

}
```

```html
//(challenge02-v2-02.html)

<input type='text' id="texto">
    
<input type='button' id="agregar-palabra" value = 'Guardar Palabra' onclick= 'agregarPalabra()'>

<input type='button' id="mostrar-palabra" value = 'Mostrar palabras' onclick= 'mostrarPalabra()'>


<script src='challenge02.js'></script>

<script src="agregar-palabra.js"></script>
```

Los errores me salen invertidos, es decir posicionado en 1 html me sale error del otro js y viceversa. Osea por ejemplo estoy en challenge02.html y me sale error del .addEventListener del agregar-palabra.js y si me posiciono en challenge02-v2-02.html me sale error del challenge02.js en el innerHtml. Estoy estancado en esto, si alguien me podría dar una mano.

Comment: Veo que aun no te has mirado la documentación de localStorage, como ya te comenté en tu anterior pregunta. No es nada dificil usarlo, tan solo inténtalo y no te lies tanto, pues necesitas algo intermedio para compartir datos entre distintos HTML, ya sea mediante el uso de base de datos o bien, en este caso, variables del tipo localStorage, que se almacenan en los navegadores de los visitantes y pueden ser modificadas y recuperadas facilmente sin necesidad de bases de datos externas. [Mírate el ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#ejemplo)

Comment: Ahora tengo que irme al trabajo, cuando vuelva miro bien ese tema y trato de incorporarlo al código. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como sice un compañero arriba, es muy facil hacerlo con localstorage, piensa en ello como una sesion por si te lias mucho, yo lo haria de esta manera: en el js 1

```
let palabrasaux= localStorage.setItem('keyPalabras', palabras);
```

luego en el js2

```
let palabrasguardadas= localStorage.getItem('keyPalabras');
```

esto te da el array directamente que lo guarda y puedes usarlo mientras no limpies la cache del navegador, para borrarlo tendrias que hacerlo asi:

```
localStorage.removeItem('keyPalabras');
```

espero que te sirva, un saludo